# I need help in proving something about a binomial series?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to prove that for every odd n>=3 integer the following series: 
{n choose 1, n choose 2, ..........., n choose (n-1)/2}
, has an odd amount of odd terms in the series. 
For example for n=5, the series is: 
5 choose 1 (=5), 5 choose 2 (=10). 
There is 1 odd number in the series (and 1 itself is an odd number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} {n \choose t} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

We have:

$$\sum_{t=0}^n {n \choose t} = 2^n$$

Also

$${n \choose k} = {n \choose n -k}$$

for any $k$, so

$$\sum_{t=0}^n {n \choose t} = \sum_{t=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} {n \choose t} + \sum_{t=\frac{n+1}2}^n {n \choose t} = \sum_{t=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} {n \choose t} + \sum_{t=\frac{n+1}2}^n {n \choose n-t} = 2\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} {n \choose t}$$

Then:
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} {n\choose t} = 2^{n-1} - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2 $$